# select values in dictionary when condition meet

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i try to get data when name in dictionary on market == 'BTC/BTC' .how can i to coding? thank you

```
def get_data_old():
    wci_url = "https://www.worldcoinindex.com/apiservice/json?key={key}".format(key=key)
    data = json.loads(requests.get(wci_url).content)

    for market in data['Markets']:  
             ############# if market['Label']== 'BTC/BTC': not working
                Label = market['Label']
                Price_usd = market['Price_usd']
                data_old.append({'Label': Label, 'Price_usd': Price_usd})
                print(Label)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
if market['Label'] == ['BTC/BTC', 'XRP/BTC']:
```

You might think that the block of code in that `if` will be initiated if `market['Label']` equals to any of `'BTC/BTC'` or `'XRP/BTC'`, but no. With what you've implemented, that condition will only be met when `market['Label']` is equal to the entire list `['BTC/BTC', 'XRP/BTC']`.

Looks like what you need is the built-in `in` operator:

```
if market['Label'] in ['BTC/BTC', 'XRP/BTC']:
```

Comment: Why would you suggest that `any` expression over simply, `if market['Label'] in ['BTC/BTC', 'XRP/BTC']:`